# How do I stop my microphone's volume from automatically decreasing, on Google Hangouts?

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I use Windows 10. I already tried the steps in
https://superuser.com/a/368007/269574, https://superuser.com/a/475868/269574, and 
https://superuser.com/a/851874/269574.

But this complication lingers. Whenever I use Google Hangouts and start speaking, within 5 seconds, 'Microphone Array' automatically decreases to random integers below 100.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution is specific to the Google Chrome browser:

1. Goto `chrome://flags` in your browser's URL input
2. Search for "microphone"
3. For the option labeled "**Allow WebRTC to adjust the input volume.**", change the value of the dropdown from "Default" to "Disabled".

Comment: After trying this, I found "Chrome-wide echo cancellation."  The default is enabled and was wrecking my mic feed, strongly oscillating the volume level.

Answer (score 2):

`Google Hangouts` in *Voice Mode* auto-adjusts or auto-normalizes the microphone.

You should switch it to *Studio Mode*

Comment: How does one do this?

Answer (score 1):

Search `chrome://flags` for `"Chrome-wide echo cancellation."`  The default is enabled and was wrecking my mic feed, strongly oscillating the volume level.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, this is good for Chrome:

- Go to chrome://flags in the browser's URL input.
- Search for "microphone".
- Change the value of the dropdown from Default to Disabled for the option labeled "Allow WebRTC to adjust the input volume".